# How to open the Mail app?Just open without sending email

Tags: ios

The requirement is open the Mail app, just like custom url scheme open the app but do nothing else.

Use @"mailto://" url will open the Mail app with a new email in edting, that's not what I want.

any ideas?

sorry about my poor English.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim No, but I changed the requirement. Sorry for reply so late.